# User and permission issue in ASP.NET Thread Timer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, permissions, active-directory

I use a [Thread Timer](https://github.com/VahidN/DNTScheduler) for Background task scheduling in my ASP.NET MVC projects.

In one of those tasks , I connect to active directory for some actions like [moving users in OU's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-C-NET-Using) and adding and removing security groups.

When I launch my application in VS 2013 on IIS Express , It work fine , But When I host my app on IIS of that machine although it has the exact same credential , I get `Access Denied` error .

My question is what's the credential difference between running app in VS ( Which use IIS Express ) and running on IIS 7.5 and how can I solve this issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS Express usually runs through your own user, which is probably an Administrator and has all the necessary roles.

IIS 7.5 runs as a service, therefore, it uses built-in user accounts which probably lacks the permissions you need.

Here's how you change an AppPool identity on IIS 7.5: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: That was exactly what I needed . Thank you